# Appending data to an element works but then I can't retrieve it

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm attaching response data to the target of a jquery plugin when a preload option is set. It all seems to work a charm except the data I set is inaccessible. When I log `$(elm).data();` I can see that the object was returned with the appropriate data set to the appropriate key. But when I try `console.log($(elm).data('key'));` I get undefined. I also get undefined when I try `var elmData = $(elm).data(); console.dir(elmData.key);`. So I'm logging the object on one line, seeing it in the console, trying to access a property I just confirmed exists and getting `undefined`.

Here is my function:

```
this.preloadData = function(folders)
{
    var getString;
    for(var folder in folders ){
       getString = 'folder='+folders[folder]+'&uri='+uri+'&thumbSide='+options.thumbSide;
       $.get(options.handler, getString,
          function(response, serverStat, xhr)
          {
            $self.data(folder, response);   
          });
     }//for
     var $selfData = $self.data();
     console.log($selfData);//Object{ editorial : "data", testingdata : 'some meaningless words'}
     console.log($self.data());//Object{ editorial : "data", testingdata : 'some meaningless words'}
     console.log($self.data.editorial);//undefined
     console.dir($self.data('editorial'));//undefined
     console.log($selfData['editorial']);//undefined
     console.log($selfData.editorial);//undefined

                                
     $self.data('testingdata', 'some meaningless words');
     console.log($self.data());//Object{ editorial : "data", testingdata : 'some meaningless words'}
     console.log($self.data('testingdata'));//'some meaningless words'
}
```

I know the namespacing is too simple, I just tried to cut out as many factors as I could to try and understand why this isn't working.  I'm developing in chrome but I've tried it in firefox also and get the same.

-----------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------

I understand what the problem is now. The console reflects all changes to an object that get made regardless of if they were made when the object was logged. So when I logged the object the property didn't exist yet because the response had yet to come back from the server, but the log still shows the property as existing because at some later point in the script execution it DID exist. Because primitive values aren't logged in the same way, the call to log the property shows up as `undefined` because it WAS undefined. If I refer to the property some seconds later, say on a click event it is defined(which is how I intended it to work anyway). I just got really caught up in debugging this function before I actually implemented it.

Comment: What's even more bizarre is that if change `$self.data(folder, responese);` within the $.get callback to `$self.data('testingdata', response');` I get much the same result except that the logged objects don't show testingdata to be overwritten yet when I log `$self.data('testingdata')` I get 'some meaningless words'.

Comment: You realize that $.get() is asynchronous, right? The `folder` will not necessarily be the same value by the time the function is called.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the folders object that I'm passing to the function is in the format {uniqueName : pathToFolder}. At the moment I'm only passing an object with one key/value pair; {editorial : './img/editorial'} so not only is it the only request sending back data that gets appended under the editorial key, it's the only request. The network activity confirms this, and I can log the .data() object wherever I please and get the same result; still when I try to access the property I get `undefined`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Nevermind, I think misunderstood your meaning. folders and therefore folder is not being received from the server, it's passing data to the server. The request only gets made once for each key so the data that's retrieved from each request gets filed under that unique name. Even if somehow it were overwritten by another request it doesn't explain how two consecutive logs show the same property as defined then undefined. I can try to access the property get undefined, log the object again see the property try to access it; still get undefined.

Comment: @user1433150 You should add the final solution you came to as the answer below and accept it - the asynchrony problem might help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

`$self.data['editorial']`

Comment: That's incorrect; .data is a function, not an array. There's an internal structure it's used to access via .data() to get the whole object or .data(key), or you can set a value on it like .data(key, value)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
console.log($self.data.editorial);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that it worked that way but I tried it; same result. Weird, huh?